# gradle downloading old version of jars from artifactory instead of latest version available

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

We are using gradle in our project and download latest available jars from artifactory. When I see the logs the url is correctly pointing to latest jar.

But once I check the version in the download location old version of jar is downloaded.

Below is gradle script we are using.

```
def BRANCH_NAME_LOCATION="Platform/Planning/${BRANCH_NAME}/latest"
dependencies {
compile "${BRANCH_NAME_LOCATION}:HspJS:"
```

I have tried to troubleshoot but couldn't find the solution. Can someone kindly help me fix it.

Comment: Have you tried running with --refresh-dependencies ?

Comment: And I fear we might need a [mcve] here, too.

Comment: We are using --refresh-dependencies

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons why this might go wrong. For example your platform definition within artifactory might have a problem. As said: you really have to get to a [mcve].